# EditText which accepts only a few characters

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext

I need to implement an `EditText` on Android which accepts only a specific range of characters, which are: "S,A,Q,W,R,B,C,D,E,U".

Comment: "edittext should't accept any other characters other than give characters in android." what do u mean by this???

Comment: do u want your edittext to accept character only from these characters "S,A,,B,C,D,E,U"???

Comment: edittext shouldn't accept any other characters other than given characters in android. i need java code.

Answer (score 9):

Just use attribute `android:maxLength="1"`, this will allow only one character input to edittext.

You can Use `android:digits`  property and specify in the XML itself what are the valid characters for you.

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:digits = "SABCDEU"
        android:maxLength="1" >
```

Answer (score 9):

What about using these two attributes in your `EditText`

```
android:maxLength="1"
android:digits = "SABCDEU"
```

Comment: This does not result into expected behaviour. See [this](https://i.imgur.com/0IlsiPK.gif) gif. `fooF` results into no text being entered, where `FooF` enters the F just once. It seems like this only works when the very first character you type is the requested character. If you start with an unallowed one, no text gets inputted. (This is with `maxLength="1"` and `digits="TF"`)

Comment: I just found a fix for the problem I described above. If you set `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` this problem is solved and the code by Shree can be used

Answer (score 1):

You should use InputFilters

```
edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
            int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
        if(src.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")){
            return src;
        }
        return "";
    }
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes as below:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:digits="SABCDEU"
    android:maxLength="1" >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the number of maximum characters edittext should accept then use this:

```
 android:maxLength="1"
```

If you want to set specific characters edittext should accept then use this:

```
android:digits = "character you want to accept"
```

in your case:

```
android:digits = "SABCDEU"
```

here note that edittext will not accept numeric characters,space,lowercases and Uppercase except SABCDEU. You have to put all character in `android:digits=""` if you wish to enter to edittext.

Answer (score 0):

> Just add this piece of code in your Java

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText editText;

    private String blockCharacterSet = "~#^|$%&*!FGHIJKLMOPTWXYZ";

    private InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            if (source != null && blockCharacterSet.contains(("" + source))) {
                return "";
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
    }

}
```

> This will give you what you want. This will let you select only "S,A,Q,W,R,B,C,D,E,U".

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, it only allows characters

```
<EditText 
android:inputType="text" 
android:digits="SAQWRBCDEU"
android:hint="Only letters allowed" />
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".